# Mobile Broadband not working on Dell Inspiron after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: networking, 15.10, dell, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I've just upgraded my Dell Inspiron from ubuntu trusty to xubuntu wily (I formatted and performed a clean install rather than a usual upgrade). All the other things are working as usual except the Mobile broadband (`ppp0`). Strange thing is that the dongle (Huawei) works normally when I run the live CD, but on my installation, the dongle connects, but I'm unable to browse the internet. Here is the syslog output when I make the connection on my Mobile Broadband:

```
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: nm-pppd-plugin-Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (get_credentials): passwd-hook, requesting credentials...
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: nm-pppd-plugin-Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (get_credentials): got credentials from NetworkManager
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix pppd[5970]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix pppd[5970]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: nm-pppd-plugin-Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 8 / phase 'network'
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix whoopsie[826]: [16:01:32] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 19 16:01:32 phoenix whoopsie[826]: [16:01:32] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix pppd[5970]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix pppd[5970]: local  IP address 100.115.3.25
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix pppd[5970]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix pppd[5970]: primary   DNS address 59.144.127.117
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix pppd[5970]: secondary DNS address 202.56.215.41
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: local  IP address 100.115.3.25
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: primary   DNS address 59.144.127.117
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: secondary DNS address 202.56.215.41
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: nm-pppd-plugin-Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 9 / phase 'running'
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: nm-pppd-plugin-Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_ip_up): ip-up event
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: nm-pppd-plugin-Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_ip_up): sending IPv4 config to NetworkManager...
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  keyfile: add connection in-memory (d3804110-9c70-456c-ac9b-7f760b90f34a,"ppp0")
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  Device 'ppp0' has no connection; scheduling activate_check in 0 seconds.
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): Activation: starting connection 'ppp0' (d3804110-9c70-456c-ac9b-7f760b90f34a)
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  PPP manager (IPv4 Config Get) reply received.
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix whoopsie[826]: [16:01:35] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ttyUSB0): device state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ttyUSB0): device state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): device state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ttyUSB0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  Policy set 'Airtel Default' (ppp0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix dnsmasq[1477]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix dnsmasq[1477]: using nameserver 59.144.127.117#53
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix dnsmasq[1477]: using nameserver 202.56.215.41#53
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ttyUSB0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'up' for ppp0
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: <info>  (ppp0): device state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix whoopsie[826]: [16:01:35] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24
Apr 19 16:01:35 phoenix whoopsie[826]: [16:01:35] Network connection may be a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/16
```

On line number 7, I can see `CHAP authentication succeeded`, but I don't understand what else could be wrong here. When I do a simple `ping google.com`, I get the Unknown host error and the following lines are printed in syslog:

```
Apr 19 16:02:02 phoenix pppd[5970]: IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Apr 19 16:02:02 phoenix NetworkManager[811]: IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

**edit**

So far, the only workaround I've found is to reinstall `network-manager`. When I reinstall this package and then reconnect, I'm magically able to connect to the internet! But I'm looking for a proper solution to this rather than a workaround.

**edit 2**

Looks like a [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1508718) has already been filed by folks on Launchpad for this. I forgot to mention it in the question, but I also get this below error dialog when I try to edit my problematic Mobile Broadband connection:

```
settings/nm-settings-connection.c.995 - Connection didn't have requested setting 'ppp'
```

**edit 3**

Another observation is that this bug seems to occur with only particular models of Huawei modems. For instance, it occurs with my Airtel dongle, but doesn't occur when I use the BSNL dongle. I also think this is linked with the interface naming. With Airtel, the connection interface is named as `ppp0` whereas with BSNL, it is named as `wwt692d89159469`, so that might be useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find a fix to this almost everywhere on the internet including this site, [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325272) and [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1508718).

Having done all that, I hereby conclude that there is no fix for this in `15.10` (as of 2016-05-29). The only way to resolve this is to upgrade yourself to `16.10`. Indeed, I should not have dabbled with a non-LTS version in the first place considering that similar things have happened in past!